# Take free space if no image css

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

I have following layout

```
<div class="post-short-content">
                <div class="entry-thumb"></div>
                <div class="entry-post"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .post-short-content {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
.post-short-content .entry-thumb {
    width: 30%;
}
.post-short-content > div {
    float: left;
}
.post-short-content .entry-post {
    width: 70%;
}
```

And for responsive layout

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .post-short-content .entry-post,
    .entry-header {
        padding : 0;
    }
    .post-short-content > div {
        clear: both;
        float: none;
        width: 100% !important;
    }
    .post-short-content .entry-thumb {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .post-short-content .entry-post {
        margin-top: 0.8em;
    }
}
```

And now it looks like this

[image]

But the problem is that, in case of no image text also takes 70% from div space like this

[image]

Is it possible using only `CSS` make text take 100% of width if there is no image ?

**UPDATE**

Sorry for forgetting to mention, that I am not allowed to use flex, because this site will be used on mobile devices.

Comment: Are you ok with using flex-box?

Comment: @sheriffderek , sorry for forgetting to mention, no I cannot use it

Comment: I now see you also wrote _this site will be used on mobile devices_. Are you aware of that `flexbox` has a much wider support on mobile's, I think almost 100%,, as it is IE 8/9 on desktop that mainly make dev's go for a non flex solution ... http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: @bkdaaqra Don't be sorry. : ) I gave both solutions.

Comment: Updated my answer, added the media query to it. Let me know if there is something else missing.

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of mixing and matching of width and flex, then yes. Be sure to run your flex rules through autoprefixer for cross browser support.

```
.post-short-content {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
       display:flex;
    }
.post-short-content .entry-thumb span {
    width: 30%;
     background:lightBlue;
}
.post-short-content > div {
    display:block;
     height:3em;
}
.post-short-content .entry-post {
    min-width:70%;
     flex:1 0 auto;
     background:Gray;
}

<div class="post-short-content">
                <div class="entry-thumb">
                        <span>Faux Image</span>
                    </div>
                <div class="entry-post">Lora liked to find a photo</div>
</div>

<div class="post-short-content">
                <div class="entry-thumb">

                    </div>
                <div class="entry-post">Lora liked to find a photo</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cmckay/jd0vxh3m/

http://autoprefixer.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the flexbox way - very short and to the point:

https://jsfiddle.net/mu3vo6vh/1/

### markup same as below

## styles

```
.image-w img { /* responsive image wrapper */
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.flex-example {
  display: flex; /* children will stretch deal with the space accordingly */
  align-items: center; /* for vertical align */
}

.image-w {
  min-width: 200px; /* try regular width and see what happens */
  margin-right: 1rem
}
```

This is the regular way with classic float

https://jsfiddle.net/mjmbm021/

### markup

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="image-w">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="text-w">
    <p>Lorem....</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="text-w">
    <p>Lorem....</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

### styles

```
.image-w img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.image-w {
  max-width: 30%;
  float: left; /* really means let other stuff float around this */
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
.text-w {
  width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`flexbox` <strike>(see 2:nd sample)</strike> would be the obvious choice, but sometimes one need a more cross browser solution (the support of older browser, and sometimes newer too, with render issues when using `flex`)

Here is a suggestion using `display: table`. It has the same great way as `flex`, being dynamic and adjust to its content.

```css
.post-short-content {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.post-short-content > div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.post-short-content .entry-thumb img {
  display: block;
}
.post-short-content .entry-post {
  width: 100%;
  background: Gray;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .post-short-content .entry-post,
  .entry-header {
    padding : 0;
  }
  .post-short-content > div {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .post-short-content .entry-thumb img {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .post-short-content .entry-post {
    margin-top: 0.8em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="post-short-content">
  <div class="entry-thumb">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/3" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="entry-post">Lora liked to find a photo</div>
</div>

<div class="post-short-content">
  <div class="entry-thumb">

  </div>
  <div class="entry-post">Lora liked to find a photo</div>
</div>
```

<strike>If you can use `flexbox`</strike>

```css
.post-short-content {
  display: flex;
}
.post-short-content .entry-thumb img {
  display: block;
}
.post-short-content .entry-post {
  flex: 1;
  background: Gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-short-content">
  <div class="entry-thumb">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/3" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="entry-post">Lora liked to find a photo</div>
</div>

<div class="post-short-content">
  <div class="entry-thumb">

  </div>
  <div class="entry-post">Lora liked to find a photo</div>
</div>
```